# Logistic Regression Predict Proba error can't figure out why?

Tags: logistic-regression

I'm getting the following error with the code: LogisticRegression.predict_proba(X)

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 LogisticRegression.predict_proba(X)

TypeError: predict_proba() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

I don't understand why, I read the documentation and don't know what argument I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide input data to the function, vector X you want to run prediction on.